# Передача данных во view Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Не найти свои данные во view. Передаю данные из контроллера в прдставление:

```
return $this->render('tags',['varInView' => $data]);
```

И очень простая страница во view:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = 'Заголовок';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-about">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <p>Это моя страница</p>
</div>
```

Как мне во view добраться до своего массива `'varInView' => $data` который я в него передал? Почитал что в виде есть доступ к двум предопределенным переменным: $this и $content но попытки вызвать

```
var_dump($content);
var_dump($this->content);
```

Показывают только ошибку.

Comment: во вьюшке у вас доступна переменная `$varInView` равная `$data`, не массив!

Answer (score 0):

ты получаешь в `$varInView`

```
die(var_dump($varInView));
```

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно заметил коментатор выше, при вызове вот такого кода на контроллере:

```
return $this->render('viewName',['data1'=>$a,'data2'=>$b...]
```

На вьюхе мы имеем переменные с именем ключа: $data1,$data2 ...
Более подробно о том, как это работает:

[введите сюда описание ссылки](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php)

[введите сюда описание ссылки](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.compact.php)

Компакт естественно на контроллере, extract на вьюхе